# Computing flux integrals through a surface (help with bounds)

Tags: integration, vectors

Vector Field $F = <(x-y),(z),(3x)>$ and $S$ is part of the plane $z = x+y$ above the rectangle $0 \leq X \leq 2$ and $0\leq Y \leq 3$ oriented upwards.

Would the bounds for the triple integral be : $x$ from $0$ to $2$, $y$ from $0$ to $3$, and $z$ from $0$ to $5$?

Comment: Why are you thinking of a _triple integral_ for the flux through a surface...?

Comment: i realized just as i was typing, thanks haha i got the answer

Comment: Alright then! :)

Answer (score 0):

A double integral is required.

$<(x-y), (z), (3x)> \cdot <-fx,-fy,1>
= -x+y + (-z) +3x
=-x+y-x-y+3x
=x$

take double integral of $x$ with bounds $x = 0$ to $2$ and $y = 0$ to $3$